# How to allow dictionary value enumeration to behave similar to dictionary key enumeration in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm attempting to pull data from a file, put it into a list, place that list into a dictionary, and then append that dictionary into a bigger dictionary with a corresponding key name. So far everything works, except the value `worddict` is only giving the most recent version, while the key is changing in accordance to its name. How can I append the current `worddict` to `bigDictionary`, instead of the last line of the file(the last values of `worddict`)

```
import csv

bigDictionary = {}
worddict={}

with open('puzzle.csv') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n')
    for row in csvreader:
        wordrow = ''.join(row)
        wordlist=wordrow.split('\t')
        worddict['y']=wordlist[0]
        worddict['x']=wordlist[1]
        worddict['box']=wordlist[2]
        worddict['direction']=wordlist[3]
        worddict['word']=wordlist[4]
        worddict['clue']=wordlist[5]
        print(worddict)
        #bigDictionary.update({wordlist[4]:worddict})
        bigDictionary[wordlist[4]] = worddict

print(bigDictionary)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, when you assign one variable to a second, you are only creating a *reference* to the second variable. This means that when the second variable changes, the first will as well.

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
# y is only a reference to x 
y = x
# When x changes, y will as well
x[2] = 5
print(y)

# y points to the same object as x
[1, 2, 5]
```

Source: [Objects and References](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/CS152f17/Lists/ObjectsandReferences.html)

When you assign the key of `bigDictionary` to `worddict`, you are creating a reference to `worddict` which means when `worddict` changes, the corresponding value in `bidDictionary` changes to the new `worddict`.

In terms of your code, the problem is you only defined `worddict` once before the loop began. To solve the problem, you need to create a *new* `worddict` for every row and then assign this to the key in `bidDictionary`.

```
import csv

bigDictionary = {}


with open('puzzle.csv') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter='\n')
    for row in csvreader:
        # Define new dictionary
        worddict={}
        wordrow = ''.join(row)
        wordlist=wordrow.split('\t')
        worddict['y']=wordlist[0]
        worddict['x']=wordlist[1]
        worddict['box']=wordlist[2]
        worddict['direction']=wordlist[3]
        worddict['word']=wordlist[4]
        worddict['clue']=wordlist[5]
        bigDictionary[wordlist[4]] = worddict
```

Another option would be to use the `copy` module and create a copy of `worddict` each time through the loop ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html)).

As a piece of advice, the [Pandas library](http://pandas.pydata.org) is excellent for working with csv files. It is well worth taking the time to learn!